# Wordpress change all image and upload paths of existing site

Tags: wordpress, path

I saw a tutorial that adding `define( 'UPLOADS', 'images');` changes the default wordpress upload folder to `domain.com/images` . The case is, the site is already launched and all images are already uploaded to `domain.com/wp-content/[year]/[month]`

When I added the php code `define( 'UPLOADS', 'images');` on wp-config.php, and unticking the `Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders` option on Settings>Media, the site still gets the images from the original links and some images are get as `domain.com/images/[year]/[month]/filename` instead of just `domain.com/images/filename`

Any help/tips regarding this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `define( 'UPLOADS', 'images');` only changes uploads for any **new** uploads *after* you edit the wp-config.php file. That `define` line is not a database query that goes through the database and changes existing URLs in posts, such as in the wp_posts and wp_postmeta database tables. URLs of uploads are in the database; you have to change them there. Try https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/

Comment: That info helped a lot. I installed a Search and Replace plugin to fix the links on the databases